# How to iterate through two dimensional ArrayList using iterator?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, iterator

I would like to iterate through two dimensional `ArrayList` which includes `String` objects using iterator. I also would like to iterate in a way that let me choose whether I want to iterate horizontally(row) first or vertically(column) by using a `boolean` value. How can I implement this in java?

What I've tried so far.

```
public class IterateThis implements Iterator<String>{
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> array;

public IterateThis(){
    array = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
    array.add(new ArrayList<String>());
    array.add(new ArrayList<String>());
    array.add(new ArrayList<String>());
    array.get(0).add("1");
    array.get(0).add("2");
    array.get(0).add("2");
    array.get(1).add("4");
    array.get(1).add("5");
    array.get(1).add("6");
}

Iterator<String> it = array.iterator(); //This gives me an error...why?
```

I don't know how I can implement the `boolean` value though.

Comment: I see no boolean value on what you're tried...

Comment: What type of error you find the there?
Please mention the Error here.

and "array" is the list of ArrayList<String>. so when you create a Iterator. it should be same type of list.

Comment: *"This gives me an error...why?"* Because `array.iterator()` is not an `Iterator<String>` but an `Iterator<List<String>>`.

Comment: since your class implements Iterator, you have to implement the iterate method for class IterateThis, and put the logic of 2-dimensional iteration in that method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Row-wise iteration is simple as shown in the @Awfully Awesome answer.

Tried a columnwise iteration with assumption that List will always have `m cross n` elements where `m=n`

```
public static void IterateThis() {
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> array = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
    array.add(new ArrayList<String>());
    array.add(new ArrayList<String>());

    array.get(0).add("1");
    array.get(0).add("2");
    array.get(0).add("2");
    array.get(1).add("4");
    array.get(1).add("5");
    array.get(1).add("6");

    Iterator<ArrayList<String>> it = array.iterator();

    int topLevelIteratorResetCounter = 0;
    int noOfIteratorNextRequired = 1;

    int size = array.size();

    while (it.hasNext()) {

        ArrayList<String> strList = it.next();
        if (noOfIteratorNextRequired > strList.size())
            break;
        Iterator<String> itString = strList.iterator();
        int numtimes = 0;
        String str = null;
        while (numtimes != noOfIteratorNextRequired) {
            str = itString.next();
            numtimes++;
        }
        System.out.println(str);
        numtimes = 0;
        topLevelIteratorResetCounter++;
        if (topLevelIteratorResetCounter == size) { //as column count is equal to column size
            it = array.iterator();  //reset the iterator
            noOfIteratorNextRequired++;
            topLevelIteratorResetCounter = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

The answer uses Iterator.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you need to implement two versions, with a `boolean` that decides which loop to use:

```
public void iterate(boolean horizantalFirst){

    if(horizontalFirst){
        for(int i=0; i<array.size(); i++){              // first iterate through the "outer list"
            for(int j=0; j<array.get(i).size(); j++){   // then iterate through all the "inner lists"
                 array.get(i).get(j)="1";
            }
        }
    }else{ 
        int j=0;                            // index to iterate through the "inner lists"
        for(; j<array.get(j).size(); j++){   //dangerous, you need to be sure that there is a j-th element in array
            for(int i=0; i<array.size(); i++){  // iterate here through the outer list, by always working on the j-th element                
                array.get(i).get(j)="1";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry, I just realized I didn't use any `Iterator`

Comment: I prefer this way, anyway ;-)

Comment: We had to use Iterator for this task at school. So `for loop`is no option for me.

Answer (score 2):

Why not try this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Iteration
{
  private ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> array;

  public Iteration()
  {
    array = new ArrayList<>();

    array.add(new ArrayList<String>());
    array.get(0).add("000");
    array.get(0).add("001");
    array.get(0).add("010");

    array.add(new ArrayList<String>());
    array.get(1).add("100");
    array.get(1).add("101");
    array.get(1).add("110");
    array.get(1).add("111");

    iterateRowWise();
    System.out.println("\n\n");

    iterateColumnWise();
  }

  public void iterateRowWise()
  {
    // This uses iterator behind the scene.
    for (ArrayList<String> row : array)
    {
      for (String element : row)
      {
        System.out.print(element + " ");
      }
      System.out.println();
    }
  }

  public void iterateColumnWise()
  {
    int arraySize = array.size();
    int maxColumns = getMaximumListSize();
    for (int c = 0; c < maxColumns; c++)
    {
      for (int r = 0; r < arraySize; r++)
      {
        ArrayList<String> rowList = array.get(r);
        if (c < rowList.size())
        {
          System.out.print(rowList.get(c) + " ");
        }
      }
      System.out.println();
    }
  }

  private int getMaximumListSize()
  {
    int maxListSize = 0;
    for (ArrayList<String> rowList : array)
    {
      if (maxListSize < rowList.size())
        maxListSize = rowList.size();
    }

    return maxListSize;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    new Iteration();
  }
}
```

The `iterateRowWise()` method iterates using the iterator, but it does so behind the scene.
The `iterateColumnWise()` method doesn't use iterator, but its safe to use.

Comment: rowwise is simple, suggest columnwise!!

Comment: Added iterateColumnWise() method. ;)