# iterating through multidimensional ArrayList

Tags: java, list, arraylist, iterator

I am confused regarding iterating through a multidimensional ArrayList .
I saw some topics about it and they seem complicated. in specific the accepted 
answer here:
[How to iterate through two dimensional ArrayList using iterator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21988341/how-to-iterate-through-two-dimensional-arraylist-using-iterator)
can it be as in this method? which iterates through the arrayList and copy the value to an array:

```
private void reassembleArray(int[] array, ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> buckets) {
    Iterator<ArrayList<Integer>> it = buckets.iterator();   
    int i = 0;
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        ArrayList<Integer> intList = it.next();
        Iterator<Integer> itInteger = intList.iterator();
        while (itInteger.hasNext()) {
            array[i] = itInteger.next();
            i++;
       }
   }
}
```

are there any dangers or side effects for using this simple form?

this is the complete program which is an implementation of a sort algorithm called radix sort.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

/**
 * Radix sort implementation
 */
public class RadixSort {

/**
 * Runs the program
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
  int[] array = {315, 418, 591, 260, 533, 58, 976, 938,};
  System.out.println("Radix sort implementation");
  printArray(array);
  sort(array, 3); // 3 is the maximun number of digits in all array elements to sort
  printArray(array);
}

/*
 * sort array of integers using radix sort algorithm
 * @param array The array
 * @param n the maximum number of digits in array elements
 */
private void sort(int[] array, int n) {
  int digitNumber = 0;
  while (digitNumber < n) {
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> buckets = initBuckets();
    // store each element in the bucket corresponding to the (digitNumber + 1)th 
    // digit of that element
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      int value = array[i];
      int bucket = (value / (int) (Math.pow(10, digitNumber))) % 10;
      buckets.get(bucket).add(value);
    }
    reassembleArray(array, buckets);
    digitNumber++;
  }
}

/*
 * Initialize buckets ArrayList 
 * @return The buckets ArrayList
 */
private ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> initBuckets() {
  ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> buckets =  new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
  // a bucket for each digit from 0 to 9
  for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    buckets.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
  }
  return buckets;
}

/*
 * Reassemble the array 
 * @param array The array
 * @param buckets The buckets
 */
private void reassembleArray(int[] array, 
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> buckets) {
  Iterator<ArrayList<Integer>> it = buckets.iterator();   
  int i = 0;
  while (it.hasNext()) {
      ArrayList<Integer> intList = it.next();
      Iterator<Integer> itInteger = intList.iterator();
      while (itInteger.hasNext()) {
          array[i] = itInteger.next();
          i++;
      }
  }
}

/*
 * Prints an array of integers on a single line
 * @param array The array
 */
private void printArray(int[] array) {
  System.out.print("array: {");
  for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    System.out.print(array[i] + ((i == array.length - 1) ?"" : ", "));
  }
  System.out.println("}");
}
}
```

The algorithm simply requires sorting the collection through a number of steps,
first sort the collection according to the first digit to the right and have all the elements that in buckest of 0 - 9 according to that last digit while maintaining the initial order of the collection, then starting from bucket 0 reassemle the collection again and proceed to sorting according to the next digit to the left and so on.

the program does work and sorts the collection fine.

Comment: Can you explain what you want to achieve? Maybe make a small example with some toy data. Guide us through your algorithm. Then we can easily decide if its fine or not. Also, did you try out your code? Does it work? If so, why do you ask? To me it seems like you are just flat-streaming your 2-dim list into a 1-dim array. Note that the code will fail if the array is not big enough.

Comment: Also note that your code can be further simplified by using the enhanced for-loop, i.e. *for-each*. `for(ArrayList<Integer> inner : outer) { for (int value : inner) { ... }}`. Or even a stream-variant, such as `outer.stream().flatMap(List::stream).forEach(...);`

Answer (score 0):

I bet the output you get is not the same one as you expect since the following line results in:

```
array[i] = itInteger.next();
```

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from Integer to int[]

As far as I understand you want to convert `List<List<Integer>>` structure to the array of the same type. You also need to map `Integer` to `int` using `Stream::mapToInt`:

```
int array[][] = new int[buckets.size()][];
IntStream.range(0, buckets.size())
         .forEach(i -> array[i] = buckets.get(i)
                                         .stream()
                                         .mapToInt(j -> j.intValue())
                                         .toArray());

System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(array));   // Prints the very same output
```

Also, you don't need to use `Iterator`, however if you insist on it:

```
int outerIndex = 0;
while (outerIterator.hasNext()) {
    List<Integer> list = outerIterator.next();
    Iterator<Integer> innerIterator = list.iterator();
    array[outerIndex] = new int[list.size()];
    int innerIndex = 0;
    while (innerIterator.hasNext()) {
        array[outerIndex][innerIndex] = innerIterator.next().intValue();
        innerIndex++;
    }
    outerIndex++;
}
```

> Are there any dangers or side effects for using this simple form?

Yes, both of the solutions are since they don't amend the original resource of input nor affect another resource.

Comment: It seems that OP wants one array. Why can't you just flatMap it to an array?

Comment: Actually it does produce the expected effect. The idea of the whole program is to implement a sorting algorithm called radix sort. i updated the question to include the whole program

Comment: @ahmeddahy: Then I didn't understand your question. I don't see any update yet. After I see, I give my answer another try. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code will be clearer if you use [enhanced for loops](https://blogs.oracle.com/corejavatechtips/using-enhanced-for-loops-with-your-classes) instead of iterators:

```
int i = 0;
for (List<Integer> intList : buckets) {
    for (int value : intList) {
        arr[i++] = value;
    }
}
```